# Sum (a:b+c) =/= sum(a:b)+c in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A client sent across some updated workings, realising he had used  `sum(a1:a2+a3)` , instead of `sum(a1:a2)+a3` in his excel. It's now fixed, but I can't work out what the first expression actually did. Can someone show an equal form, or perhaps write in words what is actually being summed up? Many thanks.

Comment: `SUM(A1+A3,A2+A3)`

Comment: And `sum(a1:a2)+a3` is the same as `A1+A2+A3`

Comment: So obviously the two are not equivalent: `A1+A2+2*A3 ≠ A1+A2+A3`.

Comment: But `SUM(A1:A2,A3)` is the same as `sum(a1:a2)+a3` Just to add to the confusion.

Comment: Thank you! Can this be extended further? I'm not quite sure how it gets to A1,A2,A3*2.

Comment: by doing `sum(a1:a2+a3)` the `A1:A2` is becomes an array and each value is added to A3 before summing the results.  So it is doing `(A1+A3)+(A2+A3)`  Where `sum(a1:a2)+a3` and `SUM(A1:A2,A3)`  is first summing A1 and A2 then adding A3 or `(A1+A2) + A3`. `(A1+A3)+(A2+A3)`  simplified is `A1+A2+2(A3)`

Comment: In `a1:a2+a3`, `a3` is added element-wise to `a1:a2`.

Comment: @ScottCraner - "just to add to the confusion", *pun intended*?

Comment: @BigBen just a happy coincidence. Or, happy addition? :)

Answer (score 4):

By doing `sum(a1:a2+a3)` the `A1:A2` becomes an array and each value is added to `A3` before summing the results.

So it is doing `(A1+A3)+(A2+A3)`. BTW: `(A1+A3)+(A2+A3)` simplified is `A1+A2+2(A3)`

Where `sum(a1:a2)+a3` and `SUM(A1:A2,A3)` is first summing `A1` and `A2` then adding `A3` or `(A1+A2) + A3`.